# Login in as Administrator on new laptop

Tags: windows-8

I am a Linux only person, but bought a laptop with Windows 8 for gaming. The Samsung Series 5 UltraBook came with a lot of crapware installed. I would like to remove some of the software, but for this I need to have Administrator rights.

So I followed about 3-4 online tutorials, but I get an error. I used the

```
net user administrator/active:yes
```

command but I get the error

> system error 5

as response.

Then I followed a different tutorial via the control panel "Manage ...". In the last step the tutorial said to click on "Groups and local accounts" but my screen didn't show this folder.

Note: I am NOT using an guest account, as far as I can tell.

UPDATE:
I tried all the options in the following page, and all failed:
http://meena-tech.blogspot.co.at/2011/09/4-methods-to-enable-built-in.html

The error is "Local User and Groups. This snapin may not be used with this edition of Winodws 8. To manage user accounts for this computer, use the User Acounts tools in the Control Panel. The method via sec-policy fails as well.

---

WARNING! I just tested windows8 and it is really that bad. I am a CS PhD student, so I though it's the users. But it is really windows8. Avoid windows8 at all costs! I had to spend half a day, to boot my computer safe mode. If you are greeted with a blank back screen, the only option to boot into safe mode is to create a bootable DVD or USB stick. (Or you might be lucky, and your BIOS is MS certified, then it's easier. In windows8 the boot menu is disabled, you just can't press a key to get into safe mode. This could have been better handled, but they don't care. Solution: use windows7 or stick with ubuntu.

Comment: The default account is always the administrator account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I made the mistake of not running the command prompt with Administrator rights.

Use <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

Select "Command Prompt (Admin)"

Then the following command works:

```
net user administrator/active:yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you are missing the Password instruction?

```
Net user administrator P$sw0rdY
Net user administrator /active:yes
```

Also start by 'Run as Administrator'.  Here are instructions I created to [Activate the Windows 8 administrators account](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-administrator-activate.htm).

Answer (score 0):

drag your mouse to the top right corner, in search enter Command Prompt then  right-click right-click  and run as administrator then this will be done.